Faster way to access the value of a huge dictionary from a huge list of arrays in python
I am curious whether I can access the value of a huge dictionary faster from a huge list of arrays.
Here is a simple example:
import numpy as np
my_list = [np.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10]), np.array([ 1,  3,  5,  6,  7, 10]), np.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  8,  9, 10]), np.array([ 1,  3,  4,  7, 15]), np.array([ 1,  2,  4,  5, 10, 16]), np.array([6, 10, 15])]

my_dict = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 3, 16: 3}

Each key in my_dict correspond to the values in a list named my_list
I used the following code to get the desired output list:
numpy_arr = np.array([my_dict[i] for i in range(1, max(my_dict) + 1)])
output = {frozenset(np.unique(numpy_arr[l - 1])) for l in my_list}
res = [" ".join(map(str, s)) for s in output]

For instance, I have a bigger dimension of my_list and my_dict that can be downloaded here: https://gitlab.com/Schrodinger168/practice/-/tree/master/practice_dictionary
Here are the codes from the previous answer:
import ast
from timeit import timeit

file_list = "list_array.txt"
file_dictionary = "dictionary_example.txt"

with open(file_dictionary, "r") as file_dict:
    my_dict = ast.literal_eval(file_dict.read())

my_list = []
with open(file_list, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        my_list.append(np.array(list(map(int, line.split()))))


def benchmark(my_list, my_dict):
    numpy_arr = np.array([my_dict[i] for i in range(1, max(my_dict) + 1)])
    output = {frozenset(np.unique(numpy_arr[l - 1])) for l in my_list}
    return [" ".join(map(str, s)) for s in output]


t1 = timeit("benchmark(my_list, my_dict)", number=1, globals=globals())
print(t1)

Output time on my computer:
2.538002511000059

This approach is quietly good already but in my practical work, I have my_dict and my_list at least 5 to 10 times bigger than my_list and my_dict in this case and this approach is less favorable and become the benckmark.
Are there any alternatives that can make this work even faster with less than a second I mean for example in milleseconds?

How does this differ from your old question? Aren't "your" codes you presented here even actually Andrej's from their answer to your old question?

@nocomment yeah that is right. Since I have bigger my_list and my_dict. It became the benckmark now. I updated the anwer now.
